# When using input type as date.. how do i get a output using echo in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<input type="date" name ="date1">
```

then

```
$DATE1 = (isset($_POST["date1"]) ? $_POST["date1"] : null);
```

this wont get the value?

Comment: Show us your form tags

Comment: could you add more information ? for example full form and action handler .

Comment: <input type="date" name ="date1" > this is the input

Comment: $DATE1 = (isset($_POST["date1"]) ? $_POST["date1"] : null);
  
  echo "<script>alert($DATE1)</script>";
this wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    if(!empty($_POST['date'])){
       $date = $_POST['date']; 
    }  
  }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Date : </label>
    <input type="date" name="date"/>    
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: right..i need to get selected date from the date picker to a variable..how can i do that?

Comment: To access date value do the following . 

 `$date = $_POST['date'];`

Comment: thanks..i did the same way.. but when i echo the value as a alert using echo..it will shows somthing else.

Comment: I have edited the code . Have a look please.

Comment: echo "<script>alert($date)</script>"; --> this will alert a different value

Comment: @Fera don't do things such this `<script>alert($date)</script>`. If you want access date value in javascript use querySelector . or assign some id to input field and use `document.getElementById(someId).value`;

Comment: Because here `<script>alert($date)</script>` $date is undefined. You can do so  `<script>alert('<?php echo $date;>')</script>` but this is very bad example . DO NOT MIX php with JS . Write in separate files.

Comment: okey..many thanks for the help friend.

Comment: @Fera you are welcome.

Comment: okey..i just use them to check the answers to correct o wrong..

Comment: Sure . If something won't work , let me know please.

Comment: echo "<script>alert('$DATE1')</script>"; ---> from this i got the date..(with the quotes to the variable)

Comment: Yes it should also work. BUT it is very BAD practice.

Comment: hehe okey.. i will get rid of it.